# Creating a function from inputs and outputs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1) This table has missing entries.  Could a linear function produce this function?

[image]

I think the answer is no because when I find the slope of the two points, $(0,0), (4,12)$, I have

$\frac{12-4}{0-0}$ which is undefined.

2) This table has missing entries.  Could a linear function produce this function?

[image]
I can find the slope of $(0,-12),(4,10)$ and get $\frac{10-(-12)}{4-0}=\frac{22}{4}$

So $y=\frac{22}{4}x-12$

To see if $(3,5)$ is a point on the line:

$\frac{22}{4}(3)-12=4.5$

But the output should be $5$. So this answer is no as well.

Are my solutions correct? And for the second question, could I have found the slope for the pairs $(0,-12),(3,5)$ and $(3,5),(4,10)$ instead and done the same thing?

Comment: The second table is the same as the first.  Please paste in the correct table.

Comment: sorry! i fixed it, and thank you. the first question i made a stupid mistake, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The slope equation for the first should be $\frac {12-0}{4-0}=3$ and the function $f(x)=3x$ generates the points desired.  For the second, yes, you could find the equation of the line through any two of the points, then noted that the third point is not on the line.